# The specified S3 bucket can't be accessed error when doing start_medical_scribe_job from boto3. My role has admin access

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Complete error is:

`botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the StartMedicalScribeJob operation: The specified S3 bucket can't be accessed. Make sure you have write permissionon the bucket and try your request again`.

My code is

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import boto3

> transcribe = boto3.client( 'transcribe','us-east-1',aws_access_key_id="myAccessKey",aws_secret_access_key='mySecretAccessKey')

job_name = "my-first-medical-scribe-job"

job_uri="s3://myBucket/myFile"
//File name has spaces in it

response=transcribe.start_medical_scribe_job(
    MedicalScribeJobName =job_name,
    Media={
        'MediaFileUri': job_uri
    },
    OutputBucketName='same as above bucket',

    DataAccessRoleArn='arn:aws:iam::ID:role/myRole',
    Settings={
        'ShowSpeakerLabels': True,
"MaxSpeakerLabels":2
    },

)
```

My role has admin access. I can upload the file on this bucket using;

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 'us-east-1',aws_access_key_id="myAccessKey",aws_secret_access_key='mySecretAccessKey')

s3.meta.client.upload_file('LocalFile', 'myBucket','myFile')
```

Documentation says that `start_medical_scribe_job` works in US East (N. Virginia) region. I have created the bucket in the same region as well.